# PHP on IIS6.1 Error log file plus write permissions

Tags: php, iis-6, file-permissions

This is a Windows 2008 R2 Standard Server with PHP 5.3.6 running on IIS 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

I have these settings in my PHP.ini file:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
log_errors = On
log_errors_max_len = 1024
error_log = C:/inetpub/temp/php_errors.log
```

Have also tried these:

```
error_log = C:\inetpub\temp\php_errors.log
error_log = C:\inetpub\wwwroot\php_errors.log
error_log = C:\windows\temp\php_errors.log
```

`phpinfo()` reports the correct values shown above.

But I STILL cannot get any code to write to the log file from a PHP script.
I've tried this:

```
error_log("Database not available!", 0);
```

and even this:

```
asd();
```

Could it be a permissions issue as I'm also not able to write anything using fwrite:

```
$fp = fopen('MyErrors.txt', 'a'); // this should go into the same directory
                                  // as my script but it, too, is not writing
fwrite($fp, "Error Msg ". $emsg . "\n");
fclose($fp);
```

I set the permissions to the folders where I'm writing the error log AND where I'm attempting to write the file using this info:
http://blog.chrismeller.com/enabling-php-write-access-on-iis

But I still can't get the php-errors.log or my MyErrors.txt to be written to at any time ANYWHERE on my system.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things..

1. Make sure `log_errors = On` in you php.ini
2. Put quotes around the path  `"C:\inetpub\temp\php_errors.log"`

:)

Comment: The first is already set as shown in my post. Already tried the second with same result. I was able to get the MyErrors.txt file writing, though. I'm just having difficulties figuring out why my script is erroring out with no log of the error. setting `display_errors=on` doesn't show them either.